# Updating container on VM. How?

Tags: docker

I specified a docker image when creating a small VM. Because of this feature, I expected a fairly hands-off way of updating the container to the latest image, but I can't find any documentation on how to do that, or at least a method that works. What the documentation says is that updating the configuration will cause the container to be updated to the latest image and the VM will be stopped & restarted, but this doesn't happen.

I've only been able to update the container by using the Cloud shell from the container registry page. Am I missing a more obvious way to do this?

Comment: What kind of VM?  Where did it come from? If you're running, say, a plain Ubuntu VM on a local VirtualBox setup, there's not going to be anything special there to manage containers and you'll use ordinary `docker` commands for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Docker Tags

The version of the image is specified in the **tag**.

If you want the most recent, use the `latest` tag.

**Otherwise, a version can be specified**.

Example:
`fedora/httpd:version1.0` will grab fedora image with `version1.0`.
`fedora/httpd:latest` will grab the latest fedora image.

Check what versioning format your image is using, and specify a version when pulling the image.

### Updating your container to use newest image

To do this, you likely need to just stop the container, specify the image you want to use, and run the new container.

The key here is to **trigger a new pull from the registry**. If you are using the `latest` tag, the latest image should be pulled from the registry. Your important data/configuration should all be made persistent through volume mounting, etc. So you should just be able to plug-and-play with this new image.

If you are looking for the simplest way, maybe try writing a script to stop your running container, pull the latest image, and run this image.

It is slightly challenging to give an exact answer on this issue because there a couple ways to go about it.

Documentation for [Docker Pull](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/) and [Docker Tag](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/)

Comment: Thank you, Brand, but I guess I wasn't clear on my question. I know how to specify the version I want. I'm looking for the easiest way to update the container running on a VM.

Comment: @GregEsres I have updated my answer. Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Thanks, Brand. That's on point to my question. I had just assumed there'd be an easier way to do this. If I have to do it manually, then so be it.

Comment: @GregEsres Glad to help.

Comment: @GregEsres Any luck?

Comment: I started using Google Cloud Run for this single html page app and the container is more straightforward to update, IMO. Cloud Run won't work for a larger app I'm working on, though. Thanks for the followup.

Answer (score 0):

Use Tag for image instead of latest.

use something like this

```
Image: name_of_imgae:1.0
```

Comment: Thank you, Dashrath, but I'm not sure how the name of my tag is related to my question. I'm looking for the easiest way to update a container running on a VM. There must be an easier way than executing docker commands on the VM.

Comment: @GregEsres honestly, I did not get your question . Could you please elaborate little bit step by step like where is the container running  and what it contains and what you want to do with that? so everyone will understand and we can help

Comment: Dashrath: IMO, the VM should automatically update itself to the latest image in the container registry and the documentation suggests that this happens under some circumstances, but I haven't found that to be true. If the only way to do this is to run the docker commands on the VM, I can do that, but I was hoping for an automated method.